# What's the best way to make DLL size as small as possible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I am using `LoadLibraryA` to load my DLL's into my project. I've just started to notice their sizes are starting to get large as I keep adding more functions, etc. Are there any options in my project settings that can help reduce the size of my DLL's?

Comment: What compiler? Some offer options to minimize size, but at raw expense of efficiency. Are you _really_ that concerned with space?

Comment: I am using Microsofts Visual Studio their 2022 beta

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o1-o2-minimize-size-maximize-speed?view=msvc-160 you want to use `/O1`

Comment: Depends on how you are building the DLLs.    Some compiler optimisation settings can reduce code size.   Some others (when compiling or when linking objects to create the DLL) can omit debugging inforrmation.    There's a limit to that though - if you keep adding functions to a DLL, or making the code base larger,  the DLL tends to get bigger over time.    But, unless you are on a system with a very small amount of storage, it rarely matters in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every other person mentioned, you can use compiler options to reduce your size. At first, try to tweak these options for better result. These options normally affect size of **your code**.

But if you have a lot of **resources** in your EXE/DLL, you will not see much difference. If you really need a small size in this case, I suggest you to use a PE-packer. A very good free PE-packer is [UPX](https://upx.github.io/).

> **UPX** is an advanced executable file compressor. UPX will typically
> reduce the file size of programs and DLLs by around 50%-70%, thus
> reducing disk space, network load times, download times and
> other distribution and storage costs.

You need to run upx as a post build process to pack your EXE/DLL file with a command like this:

```
upx --best mydll.dll
```

PE-packers compress your code and resources and encapsulate them in another EXE/DLL file. Then these files will be **unpacked at runtime automatically**, so you can use them like a normal EXE/DLL file. Even though PE-packers compress codes too, they are super effective when you have a lot of resources in your EXE/DLL.

Comment: Playing with optimization options in visual studio did not help. UPX did a very good job! (~10MB -> ~2.3MB)

Answer (score 1):

The size of DLLs depends mostly on what code is reachable from the *exported* functions. During the link phase, everything not reachable from any exported function is dropped, but you still end up storing everything you didn't actually use from the outside.

This behaves different from a static library, which also includes everything at first, but where the linker is deferred until consuming the library, so you never end up with dead code not reachable in the linked output.

LTGC + function level sections + inline everything + code folding + string folding + `/O2` is likely going to cut away a lot of the file size - at the cost of any chance of proper debugging though. (With aggressive inlining and folding of redundant stuff, call stacks stop being resolvable correctly.)

Forget about what you might have been reading about `/O1` being smaller. It is only initially (pre-linking), as it mostly prevents inlining and loop unrolling, but with advances in compiler technologies this is nowadays a hindrance for exhaustive compile-time constant expression evaluation which often saves not only computational cost at runtime (and we are often talking factor 2-10x!), but also often enough also compiles into something more compact.