# Any options to decrease the Portable Library (DLL) Size while compiling

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, dll

What is the best way to decrease the DLL size while compiling as .Netstandard portable library. I am developing an Xamarin application, where I have .Netstandard libraries referred to the UWP project as Library reference. Size of DLL is getting increased drastically and it is causing lot of issues.

Is there a best way to decrease the size while compiling or after compiling? Currently I am using dotnet build/ pack in azure Devops to generate the DLL

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Hi, I found a person had asked a question about how to decrease the DLL and people answered. Here is the website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68241147/whats-the-best-way-to-make-dll-size-as-small-as-possible

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I have tried the suggestion already, but unfortunately UPX doesnot support .Net libraries

Comment: I am afraid for now that there is no method to decrease the Portable Library size on .net libraries.